# Do electrons emit radiation due to gravity

Tags: gravity, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

Do electrons accelerating in the presence of a gravitational field radiate due to this acceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrons accelerating due to EM fields in the presence of gravity field radiate - examples are cyclotron radiation, antenna emissions.

In the absence of EM field, whether the electrons radiate in the presence of gravitational field is theoretically problematic question, because Earth is not an inertial system, so Maxwell's equations should not apply without corresponding modifications. Also the usual boundary conditions may not apply.

Experimentally, no radiation due to gravity accelerating electrons was ever detected. If the ordinary formulae are applied, the intensity of calculated radiation comes off too weak to detect.